# fetch data for vue.JS datatable on API rest with ajax

Tags: vuejs2

I new in Vue.JS development. I try to use this with an PHP Symfony API for fetching data. I'm added a Vuetify element datatable. Datable in API run perfeclty separatly but I don't display in my datatable the data precedently fetched by ajax in mounted function (and created function) vue.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data () {
        return {
            headers: [
                {
                    text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
                    align: 'left',
                    sortable: false,
                    value: 'name'
                },
                { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
                { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
                { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
                { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
                { text: 'Sodium (mg)', value: 'sodium' },
                { text: 'Calcium (%)', value: 'calcium' },
                { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' }
            ],
            Items: [

            ]
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        console.log('egerg');
        alert('gregee');
        let self = this;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://xxx.xxx/api/operation/1',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                alert('fzefzef');
                // self.Items = data;
                self.Items = [{
                    value: false,
                    name: 'Lollipop',
                    calories: 392,
                    fat: 0.2,
                    carbs: 98,
                    protein: 0,
                    sodium: 38,
                    calcium: '0%',
                    iron: '2%'
                }];
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Ajax function return good data but I can't populate my datatable with those.
I try to set manually data but result is same.

**How can populate my vue with data (ajax or not) ?**

Comment: Can you provide more details what you have done and what is actually the problem? I am using Vue.js in a similar way and I do use AJAX to load additional information, plus some request status tracking and event handling to update components states.

**Note**: You might fall in a (so called) "Caveat" with arrays in your component data: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats - reactive data cannot track changes in such structures on the fly (just saw it in your code with `self.Items`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using ES2015 because you are using the word "let".
try renaming Items to items (JS convention)

and then just copy the items and push them to your array:

```
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data () {
      return {
        headers: [
            {
                text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
                align: 'left',
                sortable: false,
                value: 'name'
            },
            { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
            { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
            { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
            { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
            { text: 'Sodium (mg)', value: 'sodium' },
            { text: 'Calcium (%)', value: 'calcium' },
            { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' }
        ],
        Items: [

        ]
    }
},
mounted: function () {
    this.getData();
},
,methods:{
   getData(){
       let self = this;
       $.ajax({
            url: 'http://xxx.xxx/api/operation/1',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                 self.loadSuccess(data)
            },
            error: function (error) {
                self.loadError(error)
            }
        });
   },
   loadSuccess(data){
        var all= data.map(obj =>{
            let clone ={...obj}; 
            return clone;
        });
        self.items = all;
   },
   loadError(error){
     alert(JSON.stringify(error));
   }
 }
})
```

Comment: Outch !! The problem was just the naming convention. Upper-case is forbidden and don't run with this. But without upper-case the same code run perfectly.